# Open a windows with OpenGL context

Tags: c++, opengl

I have worked with SDL. I would like to know how I cound open the window with opengl context on windows

Comment: OpenGL does not know about windows. glu.h can do some of the job.  But you still need to use a native API to create the drawing surface.  All OpenGL can do is draw on a context (simplified). Mouse/keyboard etc is up to the native OS.

Comment: I know it is possible in Code Blocks you can find a template, but I can't understand nothing from there

Comment: Code Blocks is an IDE you are not comparing like-with-like.

Comment: So all I want for you is to know how gl.h and glu.h can be used to make an window with context on windows.

Comment: OpenGL is a graphics library, not a display library. It specifies the colors of pixels, not how they should be displayed. You *must* either use a library (the better way), or use the API of your target platform. If you are looking for a library, look at GLFW. Trust me, if you're short on time, it's better to learn a library than learn even one graphics API. (I know at least Windows API is horrible.)

Comment: GLU is one such library. If you'd like to use that, look at this http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glut-tutorial/initialization/

Comment: @Cosine: GLU != GLUT. And GLU doesn't deal with windoing either.

Comment: @LaceanuGeorge: Plain and simple: You can't. **Period.** *Full Stop*. – OpenGL itself is completely neutral about *where* and *how* the rendering context that's used for it comes from and is created. You *always* need some form of Windowing System Integration (WSI). On Microsoft Windows that's WGL, on X11 it's GLX, on MacOS X it's NSOpenGLView (for windowed OpenGL contexts). That's how it works.

Answer (score 6):

OpenGL on its own does not acknowledge the existence of the window, or any meaningful concept of a window. You need a windowing API. OpenGL will then have a rendering context passed to it by the windowing API.

`<windows.h>` is the WIN32 API for Windows, and the prototypical go-to API for creating windows when writing OpenGL applications for the first time on a WinOS computer. I don't know what the equivalents for MACOS and Linux are (X11, maybe?) but they have their own flavors.

For a wide variety of reasons (namely the fact that those APIs are old and arcane and obtuse to work with), there are a lot of APIs that wrap around the native Windowing API, and are much preferred for beginners. [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) is one such example, and my personal preference, as it works out-of-box for Windows, Mac, and most Linux windowing APIs. SDL is another staple, though I get the sense it has fallen out of favor recently (it seems like it tries to do "too much" on its own).

I don't know the functionality of `<glu.h>`, but given that the whole thing is deprecated, I don't advise using it.